# Pear Mail not sending; connection_status = 0

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, pear

I'm trying to send mail with Gmail as server. The email is never sent, and no confirmation or error messages given. Mail, Net_SMTP and Net_Socket pear packages are installed. I set the proxy, and can connect to the internet via cmd.  The echo after the "send" never appears, but the one before does, which means the connection status is null. Can anyone see what I'm missing/misunderstanding?

php:

```
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            error_reporting(0);
            $human = $_POST['human'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $to = 'toreceive@gmail.com'; 
            $body = "$message";
            $header = array (
                'From' => 'tosend@gmail.com',
                'Subject' => 'Hello'
            );
            $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
                'auth' => true,
                'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                'port' => '465',
                'username' => 'username@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'password',
                'charset' => 'iso-8859-1'
            ));
            if (connection_status == 0)
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Before Mail');</script>";
            $mail = $smtp->send($to, $header, $body);
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('After Mail');</script>";


            if (@PEAR::isError($mail)) 
                echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
            else 
                echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");


        }
    ?>
```

relevant php.ini:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
```